# Rails 4, Paperclip 4.2.1 give error with binary file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I have following setup with rails 4 and paperclip 4.2.1

```
class Post< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :key
  allowed_content_type = ['text/plain',
'text/rtf', 
'text/richtext',
'application/txt',
'application/octet-stream']
  validates_attachment_content_type :key, :content_type => allowed_content_type, :message=> "Only #{allowed_content_type} is allowed"
```

I have this in my application.rb

```
<body data-controller="<%= controller.controller_path %>" data-action="<%= controller.action_name %>" data-no-turbolink="true">
  <%= content_tag "div", id: "params", data: { params: params } do %>
  <% end %>
```

Post Controller is simple

```
  def update
  Post.transaction do
      @post.attributes = (artifact_params)
        if @artifact.errors.blank?
        redirect_to(@artifact, :notice => 'Evidence item updated successfully')
      else
        render :action => 'edit'
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
```

It works flawlessly with all other file types. Errors out when I try binary file.
This is the error:

Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in Posts#update

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #58 raised:

```
56: <body data-controller="<%= controller.controller_path %>" data-action="<%= 
57: controller.action_name %>" data-no-turbolink="true">
58: <%= content_tag "div", id: "params" , data: { params: params } do %>
59: <%#= params.inspect %>
60: <% end %>
```

In the log it says:

```
ActionView::Template::Error ("\xAD" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):
    55: </head>
    56: 
    57: <body data-controller="<%= controller.controller_path %>" data-action="<%= controller.action_name %>" data-no-turbolink="true">
    58:   <%= content_tag "div", id: "params" , data: { params: params } do %>
    59:     <%#= params.inspect %>
    60:   <% end %>
    61:   
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:58:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__387563064_102572910'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:978:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:790:in `update'
 Rendered /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (15.0ms)
  Rendered /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (7.1ms)
  Rendered /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (47.8ms)
Cannot render console with content type multipart/form-dataAllowed content types: [#<Mime::Type:0xa835748 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html">, #<Mime::Type:0xa835608 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:text, @string="text/plain">]
```

Comment: upload zip file on firefox also fails,but well on other browsers,may be the same problem

Answer (score 2):

After spending one whole day on this, I figured out that this is caused by a bug in paperclip. If you do not have your binary file mapped to application/octet-stream it produces this error while trying to convert params to json string in the view body. You must map any binary file type to application/octet-stream in order to get rid of this error.

1.So create paperclip.rb in config/initializers/
2.In config/initializers/paperclip.rb place the following code:

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
  tc: 'application/octet-stream'
}
```

where tc is the extension of your binary file. I don't know how this will work if you have a file without extension though. paperclip owners should document this clearly to save pain to the users.